# Robolectric fails from NullPointerException because of calls to storage

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, robolectric

I'm trying to start using unit testing with robolectric and am getting a NullPointerException when running even empty tests. In my apps application file I initialize my cache and it makes a call to the system storage which causes robolectric to freak out. Any information on how to circumvent this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the stack trace.

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:228)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:168)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.os.Environment.getStorageVolume(Environment.java:869)
    at android.os.Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(Environment.java:756)
    at android.os.Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable(Environment.java:742)
    at com.*.*.ApplicationFile.getDiskCacheDir(ApplicationFile.java:131)
    at com.*.*.ApplicationFile.onCreate(ApplicationFile.java:87)
```

edit:
getDiskCacheDir

```
public static File getDiskCacheDir(Context context, String uniqueName)
    {

        //Check if media is mounted or storage is built-in, if so, try and use external cache
        //otherwise use internal cache dir
        final String cachePath = Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED
                .equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
                !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable() ? context.getExternalCacheDir()
                .getPath() :
                context.getCacheDir().getPath();

        return new File(cachePath + File.separator + uniqueName);
    }
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you have the external storage manifest permission added?

Comment: Yep, I mean, my app works great. I just wanted to start using unit testing

Comment: Ok, sorry, no idea how to resolve this exception. Making Robolectric work may be such a pain sometimes... Haven't you considered the brand new official [support](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/unit-testing-support) for unit testing?

Comment: I thought I was doing that, using AS official support for unit testing with robolectric -- This is where I'm getting my information, https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/triumph-android-studio-1-2-sneaks-in-full-testing-support/

Comment: I see. I haven't tried this functionality yet, but it should be self-sufficient, not needing Robolectric to work.

Comment: What is FocalCastApplication?

Comment: Squonk: Me failing at removing the name of the app from the stacktrace... lol, whoops.

Comment: But what is it? Is it your own code?

Comment: That is the application file that contains the caching implementation / where the problem is coming from.

Comment: OK, post the code for that.

Comment: @Solarnum : Which is line 131?

Comment: Sorry, I can't hang around. Have you check that the `context` parameter isn't null?

Comment: Gotcha. Could you do me a favor and edit the post referencing the app name please. And I just ran a sanity test, assertNotNull(context), and it is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `Robolectric` issue. I was able to reproduce it and created ticket on Github https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/1674. I will follow up with update.

One more comment about your code - `context.getExternalCacheDir()` can return `null` when storage is unmounted. You should first check it before usage.

**Update**

The issue is fixed by Erich Douglass. It is not released so you should use `Robolectric 3.0-SNAPSHOT`.
Take a look how I did it here https://github.com/emartynov/robolectic-experiments/blob/master/robolectric-3.0-test/build.gradle

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into this and for the feedback about my code